# In C# how have field that's an array of a specific Type(or anything that extends it)?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to do something like this:

```cs
public class MyAttribute : Attribute
{
    public Type<BaseAllowedType>[] handledTypes { get; set; }

    //...elided...
}
```

That would then only allow someone adding the attribute with the types that they handle if those types inherit from `BaseAllowedType`.

*Example:*

```cs
[MyAttribute(handledTypes = SubType)]
public class MyClass
{
}

public class SubType : BaseAllowedType
{
}
```

Is something like this possible in C#? (It is in Java, but not sure if C# allows it)

In Java it would be `public Class<? extends BaseAllowedType>[] handledTypes`

Comment: Have you tried [generic type constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters)? Maybe something like `public class MyClass<T> where T : BaseAllowedType`

Comment: @LewsTherin C# doesn't allow for generic attributes, so that's not an option.

Comment: @DanielMann I guess it depends on if the OP really needs it to be an attribute or if this is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378).

Comment: I don't see why this is downvoted; it is a perfectly reasonable question.

Comment: I note that you refer specifically to *arrays*. FYI C# has the same design flaw as Java, in that *unsafe array covariance* is legal.  That is, if you have a `Giraffe[]` in hand, you can assign it to an `Animal[]` variable, which will then crash horribly when you try to insert a `Turtle` into the array.

Answer (score 3):

First off, that is a *property*, not a *field*.

Second, properties cannot be genericized in C#, and neither can attributes. (And neither can fields, for that matter. Only classes, structs, interfaces, delegates and methods can be genericized.)

That said, we can take a stab at your question.

There are two ways to put a constraint on a generic type parameter. The first is to put a constraint on the declaration of a generic class or method:

```
class Foo<T> where T : Animal {}
```

Now `Foo<Giraffe>` or `Foo<Animal>` or `Foo<Turtle>` are legal, but `Foo<string>` is not.

Second, on interfaces and delegates you can put a covariance annotation:

```
interface IFoo<out T> 
{
  T SomeProperty { get; }
}
```

But `T` must be used only in *output* positions. With this constraint you can assign an `IFoo<Giraffe>` to a variable of type `IFoo<Animal>`, but not vice-versa.

Between those two features it is usually possible to build a reasonable type constraint in C#.

Comment: Thank you for helping. I'm not sure either of those achieve what I want. I believe your first one means that `Foo` cannot be an Attribute (which I need the main class to be), and your second one is expecting an `object` of type `T`, but I don't want an object, I want a reference to the type (e.g. `typeof(MyType)`)

Comment: @DonRhummy: Oh, if you want these to be runtime type objects, you are out of luck. The C# *compile time type checker* does not traffic in *runtime type information* because the compile time type checker runs before runtime.

Comment: @DonRhummy: If you want an array of `Type` objects where the `Type` objects represent types that have a particular property, just check for that property at runtime and throw an exception if given a type that does not match your requirement.

Comment: ok, that's what I'll do. I was hoping it was built in to the language like in Java. Thanks! I'll use `Contract.Requires<ArgumentException>(...)`